# SQL Server error when converting date

Tags: sql-server

I have a query in SQL Server that check if data is already in the database and if it's not then it will insert the data in to the database.

Here is the query I have:

```
IF EXISTS
(SELECT 
    DocumentNo,
    DocumentDate,
    CustomerAccountName,
    PostalName,
    RequestedDeliveryDate,
    SupplierDocumentNo,
    SupplierAccountName,
    DispatchName
 FROM 
    SalesOrders
 WHERE 
    (DocumentNo = '0000233555'))
    UPDATE SalesOrders
    SET RequestedDeliveryDate ='2015-04-16',
        SupplierDocumentNo ='',
        SupplierAccountName = '',
        DispatchName =''
    WHERE 
        (DocumentDate = '0000233555') 

ELSE

    INSERT INTO SalesOrders (DocumentNo, DocumentDate, 
                             CustomerAccountName, PostalName, 
                             RequestedDeliveryDate, SupplierDocumentNo, 
                             SupplierAccountName, DispatchName)
    VALUES ('0000233555', '2015-03-05',
            'Company name', 'Company name',
            '2015-04-16', '',
            '', '')
```

However I get this error.

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 12
>   Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Here is how the table is designed.

```
        column name          Data type      Allow Null
              ID                int         Unchecked
        DocumentNo           varchar(50)    Checked
        DocumentDate           date         Checked
        CustomerAccountName  varchar(100)   Checked
        PostalName           varchar(100)   Checked
        RequestedDeliveryDate  date         Checked
        ShipmentType         varchar(50)    Checked
        Shipped                int          Checked
        Collected              int          Checked
        OrderComplete        tinyint        Checked
        SupplierDocumentNo   varchar(100)   Checked
        SupplierAccountName  varchar(100)   Checked
        DispatchName         varchar(100)   Checked
        HiddenStatus         int            Checked
```

I'm really not sure why i am getting this error any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: try '20150305' ie. 'YYYYMMdd'

Answer (score 8, accepted):

WHERE (DocumentDate = '0000233555') <- this must be wrong

Comment: Wow i cant believe i missed this :/ i have been scratching my head for hours over this

Answer (score 3):

I suppose `WHERE (DocumentDate = '0000233555')` should be `WHERE (DocumentNo = '0000233555')`. Just typo here.

Answer (score 1):

When comparing or inserting date/datatime from a string value You have to convert it to valid date/datetime format.
SQL Server does not know in what format You provide the date value in string.
To let him know that You should use [CAS or CONVERT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms187928.aspx) functions.

**Edit:**

And, as posted before, You have probably typo in Your query:

```
(DocumentDate = '0000233555')
```

should be

```
(DocumentNo = '0000233555')
```